# Can the error "Cannot use local variable before it is declared" be resolved using async functions?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have an app which adds a `Card` widget when the user clicks an FAB. There is a list of type `Card` which is displayed in a `SliverGrid` which stores a `Card` added by the user. I wanted to implement a delete function but when i tried that i get the error "Cannot use local variable before it is declared". The `Card` is added to the list using this code :

```
  int _count = 0;

cardList = List.generate(_count, (int i) =>
    new Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text("project 1"),
        trailing: new Listener(
            key: new Key(UniqueKey().toString()),
            child: new Icon(Icons.remove_circle,
              color: Colors.redAccent,),
            onPointerDown: (pointerEvent) {}
//                deleteNoDo(), //this is the delete function
        ),
      ),
    )
    );
```

the `Card` is generated using this code (this button is defined under a `Scaffold`):

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
 onPressed: () async {
 setState(() {
           _count += 1;
     });
 },
heroTag: "btn2",
child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Color(whitecolor),), // this is just a custom color
backgroundColor: Color(redcolor),), // this is just a custom color
```

this is the delete function:

```
     deleteNoDo(int index) {
        debugPrint("Deleted Item!");
        setState(() {
          cardList.removeAt(index);
        });
      }
```

this is the `SliverGrid` where the `cardList` is displayed:

```
   SliverGrid(
       gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
       crossAxisCount: 2
                      ),
                      delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context,index) {
             return cardList[index]; // this is where the cards are displayed in a list
            },
             childCount: cardList.length
       )
    ),
```

question : can the error "Cannot use local variable before it is declared" be resolved if i use a database since database (CRUD) functions are in async?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `cardList` variable is local and you are trying to access it inside of an async callback that does not have the scope to access it. Declare `cardList` inside the `initState` and initialise it to an empty List and inside build or where ever you want assign that variable actual values and then upon delete button action you can access it.